# magento 2. 2 Attribute labels do not change even if language is switched

Tags: attributes, magento2.2

I am facing the problem that attribute labels are not changed for each language in magento 2.

[image]

```
foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {

    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) !="" && $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) !="Non") {

        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<th>' . $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel() . '</th>';
        $html .= '<td>' .  $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';

    }

}
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you add labels for store view as well? Like for English Label1 and for French Label2 etc.

Comment: I set the attribute label setting screen as an image.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the php translate method in Magento2 there.

Like this: [devdocs tutorial](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html)

```
    <h3><?php echo sprintf(__('Hello %s'), $yourVariable) ?></h3>
```

Comment: Thank you Sanne. I led the answer from your answer. It was right.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$attribute->getFrontend()->getStoreLabel()
```

instead of

```
$attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel()
```